# How to properly catch exceptions from C#'s HttpClient getAsync so the error says more than "One or more errors occurred"?

Tags: c#, exception, dotnet-httpclient

The following is some code that downloads a file using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`

```
try
{
    var responseResult = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient().GetAsync(fileUrl);
    using (var memStream = responseResult.Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.Create(saveToPath))
        {
            memStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }

    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
}
```

Sometimes I call this and a file fails to download. In that situation, the catch is called but doesn't contain any information of the issue:

```
One or more errors occurred.
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
    at SpPrefetchIndexBuilder.FileDownloader.StartDownloads(Int32 timeout)
```

How can I get it to the cause of this exception?

Comment: Have a look at the `InnerException` when the Exception triggers. What does it say?

Comment: Change `.Result` to `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` and you will not need to unwrap that aggregate exception.

Comment: @Evk will try that. you should make that an answer maybe it might help someone else too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Task.Result` throws `AggregateException`, so you can catch that. All exceptions will be inside `InnerExceptions` property of that exception (there can be multiple in theory, but in your case there will be just one). First of those exceptions (or the only one if there is just one) is also in `InnerException` property.

If you don't want to dig inside `AggregateException`, use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `.Result` - this will not wrap exception into `AggregateException` and will throw it as is.

Comment: OK i accepted this one as the answer because that was the bit i was missing. In c# if you just take the tostring of the exception, you get tons of useful info (unlike java). and also the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` was important too

Answer (score 2):

Since you're calling `.Result` on the task, original exception will be held in `InnerException` property of catched exception. You could access it with following construct:

```
string message = e?.InnerException.Message ?? e.Message;
```

Comment: does the same thing work for stack trace? `string st = e?.InnerException.StackTrace ?? e.StackTrace`
Oh I see it's similar to `conditional ? option1 : option2`
cool

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza - an `InnerException` just leads to another `Exception` object. That being said, the best strategy is *not* to access individual properties on the `Exception` - just call `ToString()` on it (either explicitly or implicitly) and let it dump out all of its information, including inner exceptions, no matter how many nesting levels there are.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this applies but have you tried?: Console.WriteLine(ex.GetBaseException().ToString().StackTrace)